# Installing an autoprefix plugin for stylus in react

Tags: reactjs, plugins, stylus, autoprefixer

I want to install this autoprefixer for stylus: https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer-stylus

After nmp installing, it says i can "include autoprefixer-stylus as a normal stylus plugin. Basic example below:

```
var stylus = require('stylus');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-stylus');

stylus(css)
  .use(autoprefixer())
  .render(function(err, output){
    console.log(output);
  });
```

"

but I don't know where to add that code. in which file and how.

Thank you

Comment: You can install it globally and use it on the command line if you would like: `npm install -g autoprefixer-stylus && stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus -w style.styl -o style.css`

Comment: Thanks, @Tholle but will it work on the server ?

Comment: Yes, if you install `stylus` and `autoprefixer-stylus` globally, that will work. If you want more control than that, you most likely have to write a custom script like your have done in your question. You would just put that code in e.g. `build-css.js` and run it with node: `node build-css.js`

Comment: Ok, thank you @Tholle, I will try